# Creating nested dicts with dynamic key and values

Tags: python

This is the text I want to modify:

```
object-group network GRP_AM
 network-object 10.45.2.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 10.1.224.0 255.255.224.0
object-group network TRA_ES1
 network-object 10.49.172.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ACOTA
 network-object 10.194.192.0 255.255.192.0
object-group network BYATR
 network-object 10.49.143.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.23.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 10.49.149.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network LKHIO
 network-object 10.49.143.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.194.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 10.49.149.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.21.143.0 255.255.255.0
```

And this is the output I would like to get:

```
create group "GRP_AM" 
 set objects "10.45.2.0" "10.1.224.0"

create group "TRA_ES1"
 set objects "10.49.172.0"

create group "ACOTA"
 set objects "10.194.192.0"

create group "BYATR"
 set objects "10.49.143.0" "10.23.64.0" "10.49.149.0"

create group "LKHIO"
 set objects "10.49.143.0" "10.194.64.0" "10.49.149.0" "10.21.143.0"
```

This is my script for the moment but do not know how to continue:

```
import re

text = """object-group network GRP_AM
 network-object 10.45.2.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 10.1.224.0 255.255.224.0
object-group network TRA_ES1
 network-object 10.49.172.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ACOTA
 network-object 10.194.192.0 255.255.192.0
object-group network BYATR
 network-object 10.49.143.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.23.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 10.49.149.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network LKHIO
 network-object 10.49.143.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.194.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 10.49.149.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.21.143.0 255.255.255.0
 """

net_obj = ''
grp_name = ''
dict1 = {}

RE_OBJECT_GROUP = r"object-group network\s+(?P<re_grp_name>\S+$$)"
RE_NETWORK_OBJECT = r" network-object\s+(?P<re_addr>\S+)\s+(?P<re_mask>.*$$)"


for i in text.splitlines():

    match = re.search(RE_OBJECT_GROUP, i)
    if match:
        grp_name = match.group('re_grp_name').strip()                  
 
    match = re.search(RE_NETWORK_OBJECT, i)
    if match:
        net_obj = match.group('re_addr').strip()    
        
    dict1[grp_name] = {
        'Network': net_obj
        }  

for k in dict1:
    obj_name = dict1[k]['Network']
    result = f"create group \"{k}\"\n \
set object \"{obj_name}\"\n \
\n"
    print(result)
```

Is possible to create nested dictionaries with dynamic objects to add network-objects as values without overriding them? If you think that there is a better approach to do this it would also be pretty welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want by gathering together all the data needed to make each nested directory as the text lines are processed sequentially. One way to do that is by using a simple (two state) FSM ([Finite-State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)) as illustrated below. I also wrapped the text being processed in an in-memory [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) text buffer to facilitate streaming lines from it via the `next()` function as though it was a disk file.

```
from pprint import pprint
import re
from io import StringIO


text = """object-group network GRP_AM
 network-object 10.45.2.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 10.1.224.0 255.255.224.0
object-group network TRA_ES1
 network-object 10.49.172.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ACOTA
 network-object 10.194.192.0 255.255.192.0
object-group network BYATR
 network-object 10.49.143.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.23.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 10.49.149.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network LKHIO
 network-object 10.49.143.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.194.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 10.49.149.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.21.143.0 255.255.255.0
"""

RE_OBJECT_GROUP = re.compile(r"object-group network\s+(?P<re_grp_name>\S+$$)")
RE_NETWORK_OBJECT = re.compile(r" network-object\s+(?P<re_addr>\S+)\s+(?P<re_mask>.*$$)")

dict1 = {}
with StringIO(text) as lines:
    line = next(lines)
    state = 1
    while True:
        if state == 1:
            match = RE_OBJECT_GROUP.search(line)
            if not match:
                break
            grp_name = match.group('re_grp_name').strip()
            line = next(lines)
            state = 2
        elif state == 2:
            net_objects = []
            while True:
                match = RE_NETWORK_OBJECT.search(line)
                if not match:
                    break
                net_objects.append(match.group('re_addr').strip())
                try:
                    line = next(lines)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
            if net_objects:
                dict1[grp_name] = {'Network': net_objects}
            state = 1

pprint(dict1, width=90, sort_dicts=False)
```

Pretty-printed output:

```
{'GRP_AM': {'Network': ['10.45.2.0', '10.1.224.0']},
 'TRA_ES1': {'Network': ['10.49.172.0']},
 'ACOTA': {'Network': ['10.194.192.0']},
 'BYATR': {'Network': ['10.49.143.0', '10.23.64.0', '10.49.149.0']},
 'LKHIO': {'Network': ['10.49.143.0', '10.194.64.0', '10.49.149.0', '10.21.143.0']}}
```